# AdMob Add Serving Limited Due To Site Behavior: Navigation

Tags: ios, swift, admob, adsense

I got a policy error on one of my app on AdMob and now ad status is **Serving is Restricted** ad serving.

AdMob send me the following screen shots:

Screen 01
[Walkthrow Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyFg8.png)

Screen 02
[Permission Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cY4tu.png)

Following is the admob message:

```
Site Behavior: Navigation Must fix
As stated in our Program policies, sites or apps displaying Google ads should provide substantial and useful information to the user. Users should be able to easily navigate through the site or app to find what products, goods, or services are promised. Examples of misguided navigation include, but are not limited to:

False claims of downloadable or streaming content
Linking to content that does not exist
Redirecting users to irrelevant and/or misleading webpages
Text on a page unrelated to the topic and/or business model of the website.
```

What I do:

1. I have fixed the button text from **Okay, Allow** to **Okay, Continue** and publish it to the AppStore.

What I Expect:

1. Anyone if can explain what's wrong with these screenshots?
2. How can I make the UI better and follow AdMob guidlines?